# Current location shows on emulator but not on phone

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am setting up my map to track my location. Right at the start I want it to detect my Lat and Long and show where I am and update the marker location when I move.

When I test this on GenyMotion emulator and input my own positions, it works and shows updated location accordingly. But when I test it on a mobile device, I do not get any marker and get the "Location null" Toast message.

Since it is the first time on the device, there is probably no last known location. Thus wanting to make sure, I took the device and moved a distance (probably 50 meters or so back n forth) and still nothing updated on the device.

```
public class TrackMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;
    String provider;
    Double lat, lng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

        try {
            //Get last known user location
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location != null){
                Toast.makeText(TrackMapsActivity.this, "Location NOT null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(TrackMapsActivity.this, "Location null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
        }
        catch (SecurityException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
        catch (SecurityException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(TrackMapsActivity.this, "You Moved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng  = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng yourLocation = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        if(mMap != null) {
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(yourLocation).title("Your Location"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(yourLocation, 10));
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try moving your phone while the app was running to see if the LocationChanged callback ran?

Comment: @stanfordude Yes no changes. I don't get the "You Moved"" Toast message either.

Comment: have you checked if your device uses the correct package name in the `uses-permission` in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @gerardnimo Yes the package name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

do you put the permission for using the gps :) 
The main permissions you need are

> android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or
>   android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.